# Sickbeard and Sabnzbdplus won't start at boot

Tags: startup, services

I seem to have some problems with automating some services at startup. I've had this problem before, but I couldn't find out the exact reason what caused this.

I've added both services to startup with:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d sickbeard defaults
```

Then:

```
$ sudo service sickbeard status
 * sickbeard is not running

$ sudo service sabnzbdplus status
 * SABnzbd+ binary newsgrabber: not running

$ service --status-all 
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  sabnzbdplus
 [ + ]  saned
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ - ]  sickbeard
```

(list is truncated)
Screenshot from jobs-admin:

[image]
As you can see the app is not starting at boot... What might be causing this?

Comment: Did you try `sudo service sickbeard start` after update-rc.d command? If yes, did you check if there are log in /var/log/syslog?

Comment: I can just start the services manually - that works. No sign of sickbeard or sabnzbd in syslog though...

Comment: Could you post on http://pastebin.com/ sickbeard init script and ls /etc/rc*.d output?

Comment: Probably script runs on boot, but fails. Could you post /var/log/syslog with all logs issued during boot and `namei -mo /var/run/sickbeard/sickbeard.pid` commad output?

Comment: Ok strange, but thanks for the help :)
Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/0ru9fH8r
I find it particular strange that they don't start at boot, but they do start with: $ sudo service sickbeard start && sudo service sabnzbdplus start
[sudo] password for mainstream: 
Removing stale /home/mainstream/.sickbeard/pid
Starting SickBeard
 * Starting SABnzbd+ binary newsgrabber                                  [ OK ]

Comment: Yes, it is strange. This can happens in case of errors. I see from your comment that you have changed the default configuration. Could you post /etc/default/sickbeard? It is also strange that there are not error logs in syslog file :(

Comment: Sorry for my many questions, but could you post /var/log/boot.log?

Comment: Haha no problem. Ask what you want! I'm glad your willing to help!
http://pastebin.com/1GESmN0y - there's a problem!

Comment: Okey, as you can see for some reason that I don't know, when sickbeard is started during boot, /var is not ready. That is why it fails. You could try to move its start at the end of boot process or move /var/sickbeard file on other filesystem. 
Do you know if /var has something special on your system?

Comment: Not that i know of. Strange. This problem does not occur on other services. How can i move it to the end of the boot process?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, is /opt.

Comment: Remove link in rcX.d directory to sickbeard and redo update-rc.d sickbeard start 06 2 3 4 5 . stop 01 0 1 6 .

Comment: I did understand it :) it finally worked whoohoo! :) Thanks allot!
Hope the same applies to sabnzbdplus. Strange problems though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the problem causing this. Maybe other people encounter the same problem.

My disk is encrypted and thus, is only readable when logged in. All program configurations are in /home/username, so unreadable. This causes the services to malfunction.

A fix i wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
DIR=/home/mainstream/.sabnzbd

sleep 10

function checkdir() {
if [ ! -d "$DIR" ];
then
   echo "File $DIR doesn't exist yet"
   sleep 5 && checkdir #loop to check if directory is ready
else
   echo "Directory $DIR exists"
   /etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus start && /etc/init.d/sickbeard start  && /etc/init.d/autosub start && /etc/init.d/couchpotatov2 start
fi
}

checkdir
```

It'll check whether the folders exist (every 5 seconds) and start the services accordingly. Add it (for example to rc.local).
Example rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sleep 10
exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log  # send stderr from rc.local to a log file
exec 1>&2                      # send stdout to the same log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution
#/home/mainstream/.startup.sh
/opt/startup.sh

exit 0
```

Script output:

```
checkdir
+ checkdir
+ '[' '!' -d /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd ']'
+ echo 'File /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd doesn'\''t exist yet'
File /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd doesn't exist yet
+ sleep 5
+ checkdir
+ '[' '!' -d /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd ']'
+ echo 'File /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd doesn'\''t exist yet'
File /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd doesn't exist yet
+ sleep 5
+ checkdir
+ '[' '!' -d /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd ']'
+ echo 'File /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd doesn'\''t exist yet'
File /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd doesn't exist yet
+ sleep 5
+ checkdir
+ '[' '!' -d /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd ']'
+ echo 'Directory /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd exists'
Directory /home/mainstream/.sabnzbd exists
+ /etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus start
 * Starting SABnzbd+ binary newsgrabber
   ...done.
+ /etc/init.d/sickbeard start
 * Starting SickBeard
   ...done.
+ /etc/init.d/autosub start
Starting AutoSub
AutoSub: Initializing variables and loading config
AutoSub: Starting as a daemon
AutoSub: Initializing variables and loading config
AutoSub: Starting as a daemon
AutoSub: Initializing variables and loading config
AutoSub: Starting as a daemon
AutoSub: Disabling console output for daemon.
+ /etc/init.d/couchpotatov2 start
 * Starting CouchPotatoV2
   ...done.

+ exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally we found that `sickbeard` start at boot, but fails.

In `/var/log/boot.log` we can see this error:

```
Starting SickBeard
/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'SickBeard.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

and looking at `sickbeard` init script:

```
APP_PATH=${SB_HOME-/opt/sickbeard}
```

for some reason we do not know, when `sickbeard` start, `/opt` is not ready.

As workaround, starting `sickbeard` later during boot sequence seems fix the issue.

---

To accomplish this, take a look at `/etc/rcX.d` folder and remove `Sxxsickbeard` and `Kxxsickbeard` files. These are symbolic links to `/etc/init.d/sickbeard` script.

This script are executed during system boot following the alphabetical order, so using `update-rc.d` it is possible choose 'when' service start/stop, for example:

```
   update-rc.d sickbeard start 99 2 3 4 5 . stop 01 0 1 6 .
```

This will assign `S99` (the last possible) for `start` during system boot and `K01` (the first possible) for `stop` during shutdown or reboot.

In this case, looking at your [**runlevel**](http://pastebin.com/S3rs6Rvt), I suggest this configuration:

```
   update-rc.d sickbeard start 06 2 3 4 5 . stop 01 0 1 6 .
```

Comment: I've tried this several times, but still the services won't start. There are not entry's in the /var/log/boot.log so i don't understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: oh, it is strange, what happened? on September 25 you wrote that worked.